# Display XML to CSV results in table format

Tags: python, xml, csv

I have the python code script. It is pulling the XML data and copying to CSV. I need the data to be shown in column format. The script is reporting the information as it is shown on the first results. I need to have it report in table format.

Example 1

```
EventID,TargetUserSid,TargetUserName,TargetDomainName,TargetLogonId
4634, S-1-5-21-2795111079-3225111112-3329435632-1610,grant.larson,AFC,0x3642df8
```

Example 2
[image]

This is the picture for the results of the code below.
[image]

```
EventID 4634
TargetUserSid   S-1-5-21-2795111079-3225111112-3329435632-1610
TargetUserName  grant.larson
TargetDomainName    AFC
TargetLogonId   0x3642df8
LogonType   3
```

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
import csv

tree = ET.parse("SecurityLog-rev2.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
ns = "{http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event}"

data = []
for eventID in root.findall(".//"):
    
    if eventID.tag == f"{ns}System":
        for e_id in eventID.iter():
            if e_id.tag == f'{ns}EventID':
                row =  "EventID", e_id.text
                data.append(row)
    
    if eventID.tag == f"{ns}EventData":
        for attr in eventID.iter():
            if attr.tag == f'{ns}Data':
                #print(attr.attrib)
                row = attr.get('Name'), attr.text
                data.append(row)
                
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns')
df.to_csv('event_log.csv', index=False, header=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: Would using Pandas to [read the XML](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) be any easier for you?

Comment: I just need to convert xml to cvs in table Format.

Comment: Yeah, Pandas might be able to help you out with that, and you already look invested in Pandas. Did you check out that link?

Comment: Hi, I did take a look but is not working.